# How to Integrate External Data resource into Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In My Fabric Network Data is coming from External Data Resource. what are best ways to integrate external data resource(Oracle database) into the Hyperledger Fabric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the StackOverflow

It is highly recommended not to  deal with external data inside consortium with chaincodes because the system may misbehave a couple of things will happen

- Endorsing may take too much time due to external resource
- Block creating may delay due to external resource
- Finally, system performance will be worse at a particular time

You can still do testing.. using http module in golang or nodejs

**Alternative**: you can make data ready from the external resource at the client-side and just invoke to push data

Answer (score 2):

Another important reason to avoid external data resources: Chaincode is deterministic, external data resources are not. If the external service becomes unavailable or returns different results for different endorsers, endorsement will fail, as the results from different endorsers will differ.

When absolutely necessary, oracles are recommended: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/cl-extend-blockchain-smart-contracts-trusted-oracle/.

Of course, `http`, `resty`, etc. are available, but they are not recommendable.